# После функции вызванной через bot.register_next_step_handler не вызывается меню

Tags: python, telebot

После рассчета курса валюты и нажатии  Вернуться в главное меню ничего не происходит.

сам код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def take_crypto(message):
    if(message.text == " Рассчитать курс валютной пары"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove (selective = False)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите название криптовалюты (пример: BTC):', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_rate)


def get_rate(message):
    try:
        name = str(message.text)
        currtjs(name) #функция рассчета курса после конвертации.
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Цена {name} в USDT = <b>{currencyprice}</b>\nЦена {name} в TJS = <b>{currency_tjs}</b>(курс TJS = {somrate})", parse_mode = 'HTML')
        tgmod.sell_buy(name) #инлайн кнопки

        
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий пункт меню:', reply_markup=tgmod.markup)
    except Exception as e:
        tgmod.back_to_menu()
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Бот не смог рассчитать курс валюты, возможно вы ввели не сокращенное название.', reply_markup=tgmod.markup)

def back_to_menu(message):
    if(message.text == " Вернуться в главное меню"):
        tgmod.main_menu_markup()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий пункт меню:', parse_mode = 'HTML', reply_markup=tgmod.markup)
```

Comment: Появляются ли какие-нибудь ошибки? Если да, напишите сами ошибки у вас в вопросе.

Comment: нет, ошибок нет